# How I fetch the data item in underscore.js

Tags: jquery, json, underscore.js

I have json

```
[{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "57d23f407d033458a7cf4229"
    },
    "employeeCode": "E1",
    "dateFrom": "12/08/2016",
    "dateTo": "30/08/2016",
    "level": "1",
    "partyCode": "P1",
    "partyEmployeeId": "57d23f407d033458a7cf4229"
}, {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "57d23f407d033458a7cf422a"
    },
    "employeeCode": "E2",
    "dateFrom": "07/09/2016",
    "dateTo": "",
    "level": "1",
    "partyCode": "P1",
    "partyEmployeeId": "57d23f407d033458a7cf422a"
}]
```

and i pass this json to my template by

```
var compiledTemplate = _.template( myTemplate,{party:JSON.stringify(party)});
    this.$el.html( compiledTemplate );
```

and my template Code is

```
<%  _.each(party,function(employee,index,list){ %>
<tr class="employees">
                    <td>
                    <span>
                        <input type="text" value="" class="employeeCode searchValuesOfTable" ><%= employee.employeeCode %></input>  
                        <img style="height:13px;" src="images/select.png" class="search">
                    </span>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                       <input type="text" value="" class="dateFrom searchValuesOfTable datePickers" placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"><%= employee.dateFrom %></input>   
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="text" value="" class="dateTo searchValuesOfTable datePickers"  placeholder="dd/mm/yyyy"><%= employee.dateTo %></input> 
                    </td>


<% }) %>
```

but it creates much table row and does not print the value .Please help me to figure out the error

Answer (score 0):

should not perform stringify which will convert JSON to string where we cannot access elements by keys.

Also you are passing json data to template with "party" reference in template accessing with "partyEmployee" .

Just change js code as following.

```
var template = _.template(myTemplate);
template({partyEmployee : party});
```

Comment: Actully i fetch the the data from ajax call and above json is a result of JSON.stringify(party)

Comment: Yes but you should not do JSON.stringify while pasing to template.